# PowerShell script to apply next available number to a user

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, telephony

Total noob here and i have a dilema... I need to apply Microsoft Calling Plan numbers to users based on region. Now what i want to do is import a .csv file of all the users and have powershell run a command that looks up available calling plan numbers in that region and then assign one to a user. then onto the next user, then the next and so on using the next available number each time.

As i have said i am not great with opwershell and i have thrown this togeth.

```
$Users = Import-CSV c:\filelocation\users.csv
$loc= (Get-CsOnlineLisLocation -City <city>)
$usernumber = (Get-CsPhoneNumberAssignment -isocountrycode GB -LocationId $loc.LocationId -NumberType CallingPlan -CapabilitiesContain UserAssignment -PstnAssignmentStatus Unassigned)
Foreach($user in $users)
{
    Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment -Identity $_.UPN -PhoneNumber $usernumber -PhoneNumberType CallingPlan                   
}
```

I have recently been scolded for using back ticks so that is something i need to ammend here but  what i want it to do is lookup unassigned calling plan numbers for the `$usernumber` parameter and apply it in the `set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment`.

I have no idea how i loop it to apply the first available number and then move onto the next..

please help.

This script has not yet been run but i dont think it will work.

Comment: How are you  tracking a plan number assigned or un-assigned, manually? you may have to provide some sample data, which is in your CSV  for better help.

Comment: Can you show us what variable `$usernumber` exactly contains? An aray of unassigned phone numbers (strings)? or an array of objects where one of the properties is the unassigned phone number? This sounds like you want free phone numbers in a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) or any other array like object that has a `.Remove()` method. Then after setting the first number, you can remove it from the list for the next user until there's nothing left

Answer (score 0):

For matched loops like this you can use regular `for($index = 0; $index -le $users.Length; $index++) {}` syntax.

Then pass the index to both `$Users` and `$UserNumber` lists: `$Users[$index]`.
Check for appropriate sizes first if necessary (especially if there are more users than there are available plans) to avoid ArrayOutOfBoundsExceptions.